# Run AJAX only when Python CRON has been run?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, cron

I'm using apscheduler to schedule a cron job to run a function every day at 00:00. Is it possible that once this function has been run I can then call AJAX to update the result of the function on the front-end?

Currently it's updating every 5 seconds, but I want it to only update the page after the function runs.

My cron job looks like this:

```
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.start()
scheduler.add_job(_get_new_word, trigger='cron', hour='00', minute='00')
```

and my AJAX like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/_get_new_word/",
        success: function(result) {
            // console.log(result)
            $("span#word").html(ucFirstLetter(result['results'][0]['word']))
        }
    });
}, 5000);
```

The function (`_get_new_word`) simply returns the new word in json format

Comment: Your client-side code has no information about what crons run on your server. The most that would be possible here is that you keep an interval running that constantly checks the current time, and if it is x minutes after midnight (or sth. like that, because your JS code will not know when the cron is finished), _then_ it makes the AJAX request. Of course you will have to work in UTC here, not the client time zone. And you might want to check for an interval, instead for an exact timestamp, because that your interval runs in the exact (milli-)second is unlikely.

Comment: Would it be possible to run a cron job to run this specific script at 00:00?

Comment: What script, the JavaScript code? No, of course not, that does not even make sense in the slightest ... that code runs on the client, and your cron is server-side.